# Dictionary 2 keys same value c#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, collections, dictionary

I want to scan a string and replace characters with similar unicode characters.

For example I want to replace "C" or "c" with a random char from "cCȼȻϲСҪҫ₡₵"

But as u know the characters "C" and "c" are different so I created a dictionary that contains two keys and the same value.

I tried using hashset as the key but I am stuck there, how to search for the value from the dictionary without having to create a hashset of "C" and "c" each time.

```
public static Dictionary<HashSet<char>, string> characters = new Dictionary<HashSet<char>, string>(HashSet<char>.CreateSetComparer());
characters.Add(new HashSet<char>{'C', 'c'}, "cCȼȻϲСҪҫ₡₵");
```

Comment: or... you could write a regular expression, ignoring cases when searching for "c" ?

Comment: Oh yes thanks I didn't think of that, but what if there was a scenario that requires what I thought the solution was ( using 2 keys for 1 value ) what should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `HashSet`, i would use a simple `string` as value:

```
static Form1() // static constructor
{
    characters.Add('c', "cCȼȻϲСҪҫ₡₵");
    characters.Add('C', "cCȼȻϲСҪҫ₡₵");
}

private static Dictionary<Char, string> characters = new Dictionary<Char, string>();

private static Random rnd = new Random();

public static Char Replace(Char c)
{
    string val = null;
    if (characters.TryGetValue(Char.ToLowerInvariant(c), out val) 
     || characters.TryGetValue(Char.ToUpperInvariant(c), out val))
        return val[rnd.Next(0, val.Length)];

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution,it is what I was looking for, I didn't think of the case functions!

Answer (score 0):

Write a case-insensitive comparer for `char`. Or use a single-char string as the key and use `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` (or one of the other case-insensitive comparers, depending on your use case).

With your `HashSet` approach you require that the *entire* set matches, not just one char. The key has to match completely due to the way hash tables work (the hash code compresses the entire key into an `int`).